# Why does allMatch function return true on empty lists in java

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Per [Java SE 8 doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-), `allMatch(Predicate<? super T> predicate)`

> "... evaluates the universal quantification of the predicate over the elements of the stream (for all x P(x)). If the stream is empty, the quantification is said to be vacuously satisfied and is always true (regardless of P(x))."

It seems not intuitive to regard an empty list as allMatch true. What is "universal quantification" and "vacuously satisfied"?

Comment: Let's put it this way: `allMatch` searches for any items that *don't* match. Since the list is empty, you cannot point to any item that doesn't match. Therefore it returns true

Answer (score 2):

Let's say I have a list of pies.

I want to check if all the pies are pecan.

So I look at the first pie and it's cherry, so I say that's false.

I only say it's false when I can prove my pie isn't pecan.

So when I have no pies, none of the pies weren't pecan.

It's a silly example, but this caveat has gotten me a couple times

Comment: Sure, we can think this way, but there is still no pie of pecan, either. It seems this is an arbitrary convention to me. What advantage does this way of thinking offer compared to regarding allMatch of an empty stream as false?

Comment: @TreefishZhang Well think of how the method is probably implemented. (The source code is out there. When I hunt it down I'll link it to you) You supply a `Predicate` and are going through every item in the `Stream`. You'll probably have a statement such as `if(!predicate.test(item)) return false;`. I.e. you will be checking if something doesn't match, because obviously if you check to see if it does, then you'll return true if any of them match. So to implement returning false for an empty `Stream` you'd have to add in an empty check

Comment: @GBlodgett So this is a case of winning by greater economy?Since we don't have to check for empty by this convention?

Comment: @TreefishZhang I mean it is *a* reason for the way they did it that way. Is there a reason to do it the other way? As I see it it's not much more logical to return true for an empty `Stream`, but maybe I've just been programming for too long and have gotten use to conventions like that